# A bazel rule "template" to generate many rules

Tags: bazel

I have some number of these input files that are called src0, src1, src2, ... srcN, and they need to be compiled into dst1, dst2, dst3, ... dstN.

I have a simple `my_convert` rule, and macros to generate full filename paths:

```
def src_filename(id):
  return ":some/path/to/src{}".format(id)

def dest_filename(id):
  return ":some/path/to/dest{}".format(id)
```

```
my_convert(
  src=src_filename(0),
  dest=dest_filename(0)
)

my_convert(
  src=src_filename(1),
  dest=dest_filename(1)
)
...
```

Now, I could copy & paste `my_convert` N times, but N is sometimes in the hundreds, and the number of files depends on some configuration... so I'd really like to have a dynamic rule of sorts where I can pass in 'N' from command-line and `my_convert` gets called for all ids in 0..N range.

What's the best way of doing this within Bazel? Is there some way to describe rules in a for loop? (I'll fall back to writing a script to generate a BUILD file with all the rules, but I'm hoping that I don't have to do that)

Comment: It looks like I can use list comprehension to define N rules, I'm only not yet sure how to tell bazel what N is from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be from some configuration? Or can it be something like "all the files in a directory"? Because then you could do something like this:

```
my_convert(
  name = "converstions",
  srcs = glob(["some/path/to/src*"]),
)
```

```
def _my_convert_impl(ctx):

  outputs = []
  for src in ctx.files.srcs:
    output = ctx.actions.declare_file(src.basename + ".out")
    outputs.append(output)
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
      inputs = [src],
      outputs = [output],
      command = "wc -l '%s' > '%s'" % (src.path, output.path),
      mnemonic = "Convert",
      progress_message = "Convert %{input}",
    )

  return [DefaultInfo(files = depset(outputs))]

my_convert = rule(
  implementation = _my_convert_impl,
  attrs = {
    "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files = True),
  },
)
```

Then `bazel build //package:conversions`.

If it can't be based on a directory, another approach is to generate targets for each of the files, and then explicitly build the subset you want. Something like this:

```
generate_my_conversions(glob(["some/path/to/src*"]))
```

```
def generate_my_conversions(files):
  for file in files:
    my_convert(
      name = "convert_" + file.replace("/", "_"),  # this might need adjusting
      src = file,
    )
```

Then build the targets you want (maybe generate the list):
`bazel build //package:convert_some_path_to_src0 //package:convert_some_path_to_src1 //package:convert_some_path_to_src2 //package:convert_some_path_to_srcN`

There's a similar way to do this using output files: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/rules.html#declaring-outputs

which avoids instantiating a rule per file (the distinction/advantage may or may not be important until there are many more files).

If it really needs to be a flag for this, it's possible though a bit awkward, because it's a bit uncommon to have a flag to configure a specific individual target (flags are usually for things that apply to the entire build). Something like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── package
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── defs.bzl
│   └── some
│       └── path
│           └── to
│               ├── src0
│               ├── src1
│               ├── src10
│               ├── src11
│               ├── src12
│               ├── src2
│               ├── src3
│               ├── src4
│               ├── src5
│               ├── src6
│               ├── src7
│               ├── src8
│               └── src9
└── WORKSPACE
```

`package/defs.bzl`:

```
def _my_convert_impl(ctx):

  file_count = ctx.attr.file_count[FileCountToConvertProvider].count

  if file_count < 0:
    fail("Must set flag --%s" % ctx.attr.file_count.label)

  if file_count > len(ctx.files.srcs):
    fail("More files requested than sources")

  # srcs could be in any order, so extract the source number from the file name
  srcs = {}
  for src in ctx.files.srcs:
    file_number_char_count = 0
    # reversed() doesn't work with string in Starlark...
    for i in range(len(src.basename) - 1, 0, -1):
      if src.basename[i].isdigit():
        file_number_char_count += 1
      else:
        break
    file_number = int(src.basename[-file_number_char_count:])
    srcs[file_number] = src

  outputs = []
  for i in range(file_count):
    src = srcs[i]
    if src.path.startswith(ctx.label.package + "/"):
      package_relative_path = src.path[len(ctx.label.package) + 1:]
    else:
      package_relative_path = src.path
    output = ctx.actions.declare_file(package_relative_path.replace("src", "dst"))
    outputs.append(output)
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
      inputs = [src],
      outputs = [output],
      command = "wc -l '%s' > '%s'" % (src.path, output.path),
      mnemonic = "Convert",
      progress_message = "Convert %{input}",
    )

  return [DefaultInfo(files = depset(outputs))]

_my_convert = rule(
  implementation = _my_convert_impl,
  attrs = {
    "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files = True, mandatory = True),
    "file_count": attr.label(),
  },
)

FileCountToConvertProvider = provider(fields = ["count"])

def _file_count_to_convert_flag_impl(ctx):
  return FileCountToConvertProvider(count = ctx.build_setting_value)

_file_count_to_convert_flag = rule(
  implementation = _file_count_to_convert_flag_impl,
  build_setting = config.int(flag = True),
)

# Use a macro to create the my_convert target + associated flag
def my_convert(name, srcs):
  flag_name = name + "_file_count"
  _file_count_to_convert_flag(
      name = flag_name,
      build_setting_default = -1,
  )
  _my_convert(
    name = name,
    srcs = srcs,
    file_count = flag_name,
  )
```

`package/BUILD`:

```
load(":defs.bzl", "my_convert")

my_convert(
  name = "conversions",
  srcs = glob(["some/path/to/src*"]),
)
```

Note that the glob takes in every file that might be needed, because there's no way in Starlark to connect the value of the flag to generate a list of files at loading time (i.e., at the time the build file is evaluated).

```
$ bazel build //package:conversions --//package:conversions_file_count=5
INFO: Analyzed target //package:conversions (4 packages loaded, 20 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //package:conversions up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst0
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst1
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst2
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst3
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst4
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.302s, Critical Path: 0.03s
INFO: 6 processes: 1 internal, 5 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
```

```
$ bazel build //package:conversions --//package:conversions_file_count=11
INFO: Build option --//package:conversions_file_count has changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analyzed target //package:conversions (0 packages loaded, 20 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //package:conversions up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst0
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst1
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst2
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst3
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst4
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst5
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst6
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst7
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst8
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst9
  bazel-bin/package/some/path/to/dst10
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.114s, Critical Path: 0.02s
INFO: 7 processes: 1 internal, 6 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 7 total actions
```